# Parallelize a dictionary comprehension in python

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing

Say I have a dictionary comprehension that looks like

```
grid = {z: g for (z,g) in grid.iteritems() if abs(next(g)) < 2}
```

What's the most pythonic way to parallelize this operation? Would python implementations parallelize this by default? Would I have to resort to using a function of something like the multiprocessing module instead of a comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

I would use multiprocessing.Pool,

Example in python3.3, a dictionary with the squares up to 10000:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> def square(num):
...     return num**2
...
>>> with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
...     print({num:sqr for num, sqr in zip(range(1,10001), executor.map(square, range(1,10001)))})
```